# Accessing a Lookup field on custom objects

Tags: soql, soap-api

I have a custom object with a mix of fields, including custom ones. When I try to access a standard lookup field, for example CreatedBy, I have to call it by the CreatedByID name: how do I find the equivalent API ID for a custom field?

In this particular case: the custom field's API name is "`OrderApi__Badge_Type__c`", how do I get its ID?

Comment: if you debug `OrderApi__Badge_Type__c` field in debug you will find it is a Id..

Comment: as @Ratan said its a reference field so you can directly use this field to get the id

Comment: I'm just trying to use the SOAP API to access data, is there no way of finding out in the web interface how to access the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom lookups follow a consistent rule: the API name ending in `__c` is the Id, while the object itself is referenced by `__r`. So, by way of comparison, the name ending with `__c` is analogous to CreatedById (it always contains the Id), while the name ending with `__r` is analogous to CreatedBy (it references the object the lookup points to).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "[System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm)":

> The following fields are read-only fields found on most objects. These
>   fields are automatically updated during API operations. For example,
>   the ID field is automatically generated during a create operation and
>   the LastModifiedDate is automatically updated during any operation on
>   an object.

- `Id`
- `IsDeleted`
- `CreatedById`
- `CreatedDate`
- `LastModifiedById`
- `LastModifiedDate`
- `SystemModstamp`

Generally you can use the "[Salesforce Field Reference Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/5/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf)" to find all  standard fields for all standard objects in Salesforce.

For custom fields the API names are defined directly by YOU, so there is no inconsistency.